# shared_ptr implementation

Tags: c++, pointers

I've written a linked-list version of something like `shared_ptr`, which gets destroyed when the last copy of a pointer is destroyed.

Aside from the thread-unsafety, is it a fine implementation? Anything I could improve?

Also, what's the best way to extend it to make it work with `HANDLE`s, etc., without repeating (or limiting) myself unnecessarily, while **avoiding excess verbosity** (e.g. `auto_<HANDLE, custom_deallocator<HANDLE> >` is considered too verbose)?

```
template<typename T>
class auto_
{
    T *pValue;
    mutable const auto_<T> *pPrev, *pNext;

public:
    auto_()           : pValue(new T()),  pPrev(NULL), pNext(NULL) { }
    auto_(T *pValue)  : pValue(pValue),   pPrev(NULL), pNext(NULL) { }
    auto_(const T &v) : pValue(new T(v)), pPrev(NULL), pNext(NULL) { }
    auto_(const auto_<T> &o) : pValue(o.pValue), pPrev(&o), pNext(NULL) { o.pNext = this; }

    virtual ~auto_()
    {
        const auto_<T> *const pPrev = this->pPrev, *const pNext = this->pNext;
        if (pPrev != NULL) { pPrev->pNext = pNext; }
        if (pNext != NULL) { pNext->pPrev = pPrev; }
        if (pPrev == NULL && pNext == NULL) { delete this->pValue; }
        this->pPrev = this->pNext = NULL;
        this->pValue = NULL;
    }

    auto_<T>& operator=(const auto_<T>& other)
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            this->~auto_();
            this->pValue = other.pValue;
            this->pPrev = &other;
            this->pNext = other.pNext;
            if (other.pNext != NULL) { other.pNext->pPrev = this; }
            other.pNext = this;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    operator   T&() /*also const version*/ { return *this->pValue; }
    operator   T*() /*also const version*/ { return  this->pValue; }
    T* operator->() /*also const version*/ { return  this->pValue; }
    T& operator *() /*also const version*/ { return *this->pValue; }
};
```

Sample usage:

```
template<typename T>
T recurse(T value, int depth)
{
    if (depth > 0) { T result = recurse(value, depth - 1); return result; }
    else { return value; }
}

auto_<int> test()
{
    printf("Value: %d\n", *recurse(auto_<int>(10), 3));
    auto_<int> p1 = recurse<auto_<int> >(5, 3);
    printf("Value: %d\n", *p1);
    auto_<int> p2 = 3;
    p1 = p2;
    p2 = p1;
    return p2;
}
```

Comment: Why a linked list? Instead of a reference counter which would be more effective and simpler?

Comment: @ronag: Because this is *purely stack-based*. Using a reference counter would require heap allocation.

Comment: I'm not convinced that a "purely stack based" implementation is better. Firstly because if it was better then shared_ptr would probably have used it. Secondly, a reference counter would require a single heap allocation, whereas your stack-based solution requires several extra assignments and checks for every copy.

Comment: If you want to use this class I would strongly suggest that you write unit tests for this class, as it might be easier to verify its correctness.

Comment: @ronag: Huh? *`If it was better then shared_ptr would probably have used it.`*? I don't follow that, sorry. A "single heap allocation" (and deallocation) is not exactly trivial -- I'm pretty darn sure that it can't be cheaper than a simple unlink operation. (Feel free to prove me wrong!) And in terms of storage, I'm pretty sure it's *also* less efficient because heap allocations also require metadata anyway. Do you have any reason to believe a heap allocation is more efficient in any respect?

Comment: heap allocation is not more efficient, however, you will only do a single heap allocation for ALL smart pointers pointing to the SAME resource, and then just a counter inc/dec when creating/destroying smart pointer instances. While in your case you the creation of the first smart pointer might have less overhead, however you will have a higher overhead (6 assignments vs 1 inc/dec) creating/destroying copies if that smart pointer. So it's about having one "large" overhead vs many "medium" overheads.

Comment: Also, if you use std::make_shared then there is no overhead for allocating the reference counter. Since it is allocated together with the actual resource in a single allocation. Which I believe means that the shared_ptr way is most efficient, unless I missed something?

Comment: @ronag: Ah, but *you don't have to pass my handle by value*! You can still pass `auto_` by reference, and only copy it when necessary. That effectively removes all the link/unlink costs (which is already noise anyway), except in those cases where the scopes are escaped -- which can again be optimized away with RVO. So, really, these handles would have *zero* cost unless they actually *need* to be copied (which is probably to a  heap object) -- and if they are, then this still (1) is not really happening more often than ref counting, and (2) has better spatial locality/is faster.

Comment: Actually, if you use std::make_shared then I think shared_ptr is faster than your implementation in all cases. The construction only requires a single allocation + assignment. While yours requires 1 allocation + 2 assignments. Copying/destroying requires only reference inc/dec, while your requires 4 branches and 6 assignments. Also I don't think there is much of a difference in cache locality, since the reference counter is as likely to be in the cache (since its written to the cache in constructor), as your stack allocated variables. Although I might be wrong regarding the cache.

Comment: @ronag: But don't forget that heap management is (1) nondeterministic, and (2) nontrivial. Point (1) means that `shared_ptr` is *amortized* constant-time, whereas `auto_` is *literally* constant-time. Point (2) means that `shared_ptr`'s heap allocation is adding pressure to the heap (and hence evicting more data from the cache which you don't need, regarding other heap blocks), which is going to affect everything you do afterward. But either way, *why would 4 branches and 6 assignments* make any difference in the first place? Shouldn't you pass them **by reference** anyway, if in a tight loop?

Comment: With std::make_shared you will have the same heap management as in your case, you do a new T(), while make_shared will probably do something like new obj_with_ref_count<T>(), e.i the same heap management cost. The only case where your implementation is faster is when the pointer to the resource alrdy exists.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1280/discussion-between-ronag-and-mehrdad)

Comment: custom_deallocator<foo>: you could type traits or some (overriden) global function (see Boost.Smart_ptr, intrusive_prt). The problem with HANDLE is that it is already a pointer (you do not want a HANDLE* pointer)

Comment: @ronag: **[Are you sure](https://www.ideone.com/67NeA)** that my implementation is slower?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ideone, I don't think its good for benchmarks since it probably doesn't optimize much, and your benchmark seems a bit wierd, it doesn't rly do any "heap allocation" test, since 99% of the time is spent in the bintree thing. I rewrote it and compiled it on MSVC 2010, http://pastebin.com/Wtpemseu, results: "Allocation auto_: 4337ms" "Allocation shared_ptr: 4081ms", "Copying auto_: 3021ms" "Copying shared_ptr: 3160ms. Which means that shared_ptr is as fast or faster to allocate, and slower to copy (probably due to thread-safety, unsure).

Comment: @ronag: I get the *same results* as I got on IDEone with my VC++ 2008 with full optimizations (I have no idea how you have a Visual Studio 2011, the latest is 2010...). Did you turn on optimizations in your own build?

Comment: It should say MSVC 2010 ofc. I got the same results as you with your benchmark. However, I thought your benchmark was flawed (for the reasons I mentioned) and wrote another one (which I linked).

Comment: @ronag: `it doesn't rly do any "heap allocation" test, since 99% of the time is spent in the bintree thing` -> I don't understand how that's "flawed". Why *should* it do any heap allocation? Isn't the *entire point* of my class to **avoid** heap allocations while copying?

Comment: You argument as I understood from our previous discussion was, "auto_" is faster to  create, while it doesn't matter that its slower to copy since you will pass it by reference". The benchmark show just the opposite, shared_ptr is faster to create and slower to copy. Your benchmark is "flawed" since it tests the copying, which you stated previously was not of interest. I'm a bit confused...

Comment: @ronag: *Sigh.... you *claimed* that it's slower to copy, and I told you it doesn't matter. I assumed you might be correct, and so I said you can pass it by reference, but in my benchmark, I showed you that's in fact not even the case. As for the *creation*, *[mine is also faster](https://www.ideone.com/WxwwL)* -- I have no idea what your benchmark was doing.

Comment: You cannot compare with shared_ptrs' copying since it has thread-safety overhead, which I mentioned above.

Comment: @ronag: *Copying?* I thought you were talking about *creation*? Your argument is so confusing...

Comment: I give up, this discussion is not getting much farther. Thanks for an interesting discussion so far. And good luck with your auto_ class.

Comment: @Mehrdad: `shared_ptr` has one big advantage over your class. It is thread safe, which means that more than one thread can share the object being pointed to. Yours cannot do that. Being able to do that incurs significant overhead when fiddling with the reference count.

Comment: @Omnifarious: Did you happen to read the *first sentence* of the second paragraph in my question (excluding the "Edit" section)?

Comment: @Mehrdad - _shrug_ It's still a big advantage. Your disclaimer doesn't change that.

Comment: @Omnifarious: Yup, it is; I wasn't claiming otherwise. That's why I acknowledged the fact while posting this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Implementing your own smart pointer is very hard please don't try.

If it is just to try and learn then fine you may learn something but after practicing go back to one that has been tested and is know to work.

20 seconds into looking Bug 1:

```
int main()
{
    auto_<int>   x;
    auto_<int>   y(x);
    auto_<int>   z(x);
}
```

Problem caused by this line:

```
auto_(const auto_<T> &o)
   : pValue(o.pValue)
   , pPrev(&o)
   , pNext(NULL)
{
    o.pNext = this;   // Here you are overwriting x.pNext when building z
}                     // It may or may not cause a bug but it was definitely
                      // not what you intended to do.
```

You now have

```
pNext List
[X] -> [Z] -> |    Y/Z point at nothing
       [Y] -> |    X   points at Z

pPrev List
[Y] -> [X] -> |    Y/Z point at X
[Z] ----^          X   points at nothing.

                   One assumes you are trying to create a circular list!
```

#### Don't use hungarian notation

```
pValue
```

Do you really want to bind your object to always using pointers?
Just use logical names for the members try not to encode type information into the name of the member it already has that information in its type.

#### Style Tip

Don;t do this:

```
    const auto_<T> *const pPrev = this->pPrev, *const pNext = this->pNext;
```

It really hard to read. You are doing complex enough stuff try and make it easy to read

```
    auto_<T> const* const pPrev = this->pPrev
    auto_<T> const* const pNext = this->pNext;
```

#### Don't do pointless work

```
    this->pPrev = this->pNext = NULL;
    this->pValue = NULL;
```

This does nothing. This object is going to be destroyed. Therefore these variables do not exist after the destructor exists. So little point in playing with their values just before destruction.

#### Don't manually call the destructor

```
        this->~auto_();
```

Nobody expects people to do this. Its just confusing. Move the code in the destructor into another method and call that.

#### Broken link

If sombody inserts a NULL pointer into your smart pointer you are asking for trouble when they de-reference it.

```
auto_<int>  x(NULL); // valid constructor
```

This is going to blow up

```
operator   T&() /*also const version*/ { return  *this->pValue; }
```

You either need to check the ptr on construction (to make sure it is never NULL) or if you allow NULL pointers then you need to check when the object is used.

#### Specialization

To avoid repeating yourself allow your code to be specialized by a second template parameter that understands how to reclaim the resources of different types. The default version just calls delete but this allows you to use specialize it for handles etc.

#### Circular lists are easier with no NULL pointers.

```
template<typename T>
struct Deleter
{
    void operator()(T* ptr) const { delete ptr;}
};

template<typename T, typename D = Deleter<T> >
class my_auto
{
    T *value;
    mutable const my_auto<T>* prev;
    mutable const my_auto<T>* next;

    public:
    // set up the chain to be circular pointing at just itself.
    // This way next/prev will never be NULL and we don't need to test
    my_auto()           : value(new T()),  prev(this), next(this) { }
    my_auto(T *value)   : value(value),    prev(this), next(this) { if (value == 0) throw int(1);}
    my_auto(const T &v) : value(new T(v)), prev(this), next(this) { }

    // insertInto() will do that appropriate set up.
    // We are currently not in a chain and have no value to release.
    my_auto(const my_auto<T> &o)
    {
        insertInto(o);
    }

    my_auto<T>& operator=(const my_auto<T>& other)
    {
        // Check for assignment to self
        if (this != &other)
        {
            testAndDestroy();
            removeFromChain();
            insertInto(other);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~my_auto()
    {
        testAndDestroy();
        removeFromChain();
    }

    private:
        // If next == this then this is the only node in the chain
        // So we destroy the data portion.
        void testAndDestroy()
        {
            if (next == this)
            {
                D     deleter;
                deleter(value);
            }
        }
        // Unlink this node from the chain.
        // If we are the only link in the chain it still works
        // we just remain linked to ourselves.
        void removeFromChain()
        {
            // Remove this node from the chain
            prev->next  = next;
            next->prev  = prev;
        }
        // Insert into another chain.
        // Assumes that we are not part of another chain
        // and that our data has already been released as required.
        void insertInto(const my_auto<T>& other)
        {
            value           = other.value;

            next            = other.next;
            other.next.prev = this;

            prev            = other;
            other.next      = this;
        }
};
```

If you want to use a non circular list (then you need to fix the constructor)

```
auto_(const auto_<T> &o)
    : pValue(o.pValue)
    , pPrev(&o)
    , pNext(o.pNext)                      // Fix this line
{
    if (o.pNext) { o.pNext.prev = this;}  // Add this line
    o.pNext = this;
}
// Your code assumes the node is always added to the end of the list
// You can not guarantee this. So you need to take account of being
// inserted into the middle.
```

Comment: I second "Implementing your own smart pointer is very hard please don't try.".

Comment: Ah, I think you're right about `pNext(NULL)` -- I think it should have said `pNext(other.pNext)` instead; thanks for catching that! Regarding Hungarian notation: I don't *normally* use it, but I make an exception for pointers... I feel like it makes more sense, since `pValue` *has* to be a pointer (since my `auto_` is wrapping pointers).

Comment: @ronag: I feel that's a depressing answer. "You can't write good code, so don't try."

Comment: @Mehrdad: Even with that fix your code is wrong. You never update enough pointer to maintain the list correctly.

Comment: @Mehrdad: That is not what he is saying. smart pointers are very very hard to write correctly. Even when you fix the obvious stuff I have pointed out you are still going to get it wrong (the non obvious stuff is hard and you are not skilled enough to get the obvious stuff). Don't feel bad it took ten years (and thousands of people looking) to get the standard smart pointers to work in all situations. So don't expect to write your own smart pointers and expect them to work in a single try. They will fail when you start to do anything non trivial. **Use it to learn but not in real code**.

Comment: @Tux-D: I'm still confused at what you mean by your statement, *"You never update enough pointer to maintain the list correctly."*... What do you mean by "enough pointer"? What exactly am I missing?

Comment: @Mehrdad: You are trying to maintain a list of smart pointers that all point at the same resource. You are not doing this **`incorrectly`**. In both the constructor and the assignment operator you are doing it incorrectly. I have provided an implementation that maintains the list correctly.

Comment: @Tux-D: Thanks for the "correct" implementation, but I'm still confused at why *mine* is wrong. Is the only difference in whether or not the pointers can be `NULL`? If so, why is that considered to be a problem? (Isn't dereferencing a pointer undefined *anyway*?) If not, then what is the issue? I feel like I've missed it.

Comment: OK. Re-read your code. It now looks fine, sorry I was obviously rushing the review yesterday.

Comment: @Tux-D: Cool, thanks for taking a look at it! If there is no issue with the `NULL`s then I think it might not be a bad idea to remove it from the answer, since it might be misleading for whomever who sees this later.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I already did. It was just the assignment operator I made a mistake on. The constructor is still broken. The technique for not using NULL is just a well know better technique for this situation (you want to use a circular list hence no NULL(s)). It makes the code easier to write/read. (You are not the first to implement smart pointers using a list).

Comment: @Tux-D: Then I *still* don't understand what's "broken" about my constructor. I thought changing `pNext(NULL)` to `pNext(other.pNext)` fixes the issue, doesn't it? Which constructor are you referring to?

Comment: @Mehrdad: See new edit to show fix for constructor.

Comment: @Tux-D: Oooooooh of *course*! thanks a lot for pointing it out! +1 :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Rule of thumb. Doubly linked lists have four pointers that need to be modified to insert an item (always count and make sure you have tried to update four pointers).

Comment: @Tux-D: Yeah, I "know" that but I still mess up the last link every single time. xD

Comment: @Tux-D Why is the destructor virtual ? Well it helps if someone wants to inherit my_auto, then it is useful. For me, removing the virtual will make people stop inheriting this class w/o any necessity.

Comment: @Jagannath: Bug. It should probably not be there. Thanks. See smart pointers are very hard to write well.

Comment: Regarding the manual destructor call, being confusing is not the only problem. An object's lifetime ends when the destructor is called. After that the object is no more and everything you try to do with it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention -- I've been using this extensively (after a few tweaks of course) and it's been working beautifully so far. It's great (and fast) to not have to worry about heap allocations. :)

Comment: @MartinYork: "Implementing your own smart pointer is very hard please don't try."

Umm.... that's pretty poor. The individual is clearly attempting to improve his programming skills.

Comment: @Greg I cover that in the second sentence. `If it is just to try and learn then fine you may learn something but after practicing go back to one that has been tested and is know to work.` Use one that everybody knows works. If you want to learn fine.

Answer (score 0):

You post a link to benchmark results, which are very interesting. They show your pointer class to be significantly faster than the boost `shared_ptr` class.

There are a few critiques here. Your benchmarking technique is a bit crude, and it's very heavily oriented towards making copies of the pointer. While most pointers are copied a bit more than they're created, the ratio is more like 5 to 1, not 16 million to 1.

But, of course, that makes your benchmark all the more interesting since `shared_ptr`s big weakness as compared to yours is the requirement of allocating memory when the pointer is first created. Of course, using `make_shared` gets rid of this overhead and, as a bonus, increases locality of reference since the reference count and data pointed at are close to each other in memory.

I ran this benchmark on a Linux Opteron based system with Boost 1.47 and got nearly identical results to yours.

Then I transformed your program slightly. C++11 has a `shared_ptr` as part of the standard library. I changed your program to use this instead and compiled for C++11.

After this, the performance of your class was only slightly better than the standard library class. 960ms vs. 800ms.

I then recompiled with the `-pthread` option and the performance of the standard library `shared_ptr` dropped drastically. 1660ms vs 820ms.

This confirms my theory that Boost's poor performance is very likely due to thread safety. Changing a reference count in a thread-safe way is much slower because the CPU is force to use atomic memory operations.

Anyway, the difference between your class and the standard library class is so small in a non-threaded context that I wouldn't feel it was worth it to use your special class vs. one that was part of the standard library.

If you want to re-create the benchmark I ran, change these lines in your benchmark:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
using namespace boost;
```

to

```
#include <memory>
using ::std::shared_ptr;
using ::std::make_shared;
```

And compile with a compiler that supports C++11. g++ can be made to support C++11 by passing the `-std=gnu++0x` or `-std=c++0x` options. By default the GNU compiler will compile in single-threaded mode. In order to get it to compile programs that will run properly with multiple threads, the `-pthread` option needs to be passed to both the compiler and linker.

Comment: Oh lol, so it really wasn't different. xD I just tried it on MSVC 2010 (it only comes with a multithreaded library -- but that's what I'm using for my projects) and got `610 ms` vs `1595 ms`. So I guess it's a factor of ~3 difference for MSVC projects?

Comment: @Mehrdad: _nod_ Apparently so. Do you realize why the multi-threaded implementation is so much slower?

Comment: lol, of course; I knew it before I posted this.